# TypeError: Class constructor TranslateHttpLoader cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angular

I got this error when configure i18n for translation in angular 8. I tried many references still lack to find out the solution on this error

this is my sample code

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I was working with this, I faced a similar issue.

in app.module.ts, under imports check if your useFactory has the name HttpLoaderFactory. Mine was not the function name at first and I got this error.